# Enzyme : mount does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme, jestjs

I am trying to write my first test using `Enzyme` and `Jest`. I end up converting the wrapper to Html() string always. And then assert like below i.e. directly on html string using `indexOf` merhod - instead of directly using the enzyme apis on the  mount wrapper object to find dom objects.

```
  const wrapper = mount(<Admin title="Mock Admin Client"  restClient={ jest.fn().mockImplementation(()=>{
                                    return {
                                                total : 1,
                                                data: 
                                                    [{
                                                        id: "0300b4cf-4888-4e73-b4e1-25cf4686e05c",
                                                        name: "cat2",
                                                        displaySequence: 121
                                                    }]
                                            }
                                })}>
                                    <Resource options={{ label: 'Categories' }} name="category" list={CategoryList}/>                                    
                                </Admin>
                             );
                  console.log(wrapper)           ;
        expect(wrapper.children().html().indexOf("cat2") > 0).toBeTruthy();
        expect(wrapper.children().html().indexOf("0300b4cf-4888-4e73-b4e1-25cf4686e05c") > 0).toBeTruthy();
        expect(wrapper.children().html().indexOf("121") > 0).toBeTruthy();
```

console.log(wrapper)    always prints this :

> console.log containers__tests__\Categories.test.tsx:20
>       ReactWrapper { length: 1 }

Also, if I try to use `shallow` or `render` - that never works. i.e. `.html()` does not output anything on those functions. Only it works on `mount`

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem you have experienced is because of the async rest call. Testing async React code with Enzyme and Jest is tricky. Important part is utilizing Jasmine/Jest [done method](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support). Here is an example from [a great article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/testing-asynchronous-and-synchronous-react-components-with-jest-and-enzyme-a979ab425aa1):

```
it('should display message retrieved with ajax request', 
    async (done) => {
       const fakePromise = Promise.resolve(mockResponse(
           200,
           null,
           JSON.stringify({message: message})
        ));
        window.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => {
            return fakePromise
        });
        expect.assertions(2); //check if all assertions called
        const info = mount(<Info infoUrl = {url} />);
        await Promise.all([fakePromise]);
        setImmediate(() => {
            try {
                expect(info).toHaveState('message', message);
                expect(info).toIncludeText(message);
            } catch (e) {
                done.fail(e);
            }
            done();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If you see my mock i.e. `jest.fn().mockImplementation(..)`, there is no async call. I am not sure what are you referring to as `async` here ?

Comment: I thought that the restClient property is called async. Anyway, what is the implementation of the Admin component?